# My VBS script is looking for file in wrong directory

Tags: vba, excel

[image: project structure]

The macro I had written was working fine until I happened to change the file path to a relative one.

Here is the actual macro:

```
Public Sub refreshXLS()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\requiredSource\TestData1.xlsm"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Path)

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Right(file.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(file.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open Path & file.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
         End If
    Next

        With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I updated it to:

```
Public Sub refreshXLS()

    Dim xlApp
    Dim xlBook
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fullpath
    fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Path = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullpath & "\TestData1.xlsm")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Path)

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    For Each file In folder.Files
        If Right(file.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(file.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
            Workbooks.Open Path & file.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
         End If
    Next

        With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I also tried to use:

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:= ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestData1.xlms".
```

This didn't help either.

Comment: `Path = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullpath & "\TestData1.xlsm")` is now a Workbook, not a String`.

Comment: Change `Path = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullpath & "\TestData1.xlsm")` to `Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullpath & "\TestData1.xlsm")`

Comment: @PatricK: You may want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
Public Sub refreshXLS()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim extension As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    For Each file In fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path).Files
        extension = LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file.Path))
        If extension = "xlsx" Or extension = "xls" Then
            With Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
                .UpdateLink Name:=.LinkSources
                .Close True
            End With
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
End Sub
```

This will process all the files in the same folder where the current `xlsm` file is stored. If the files to be processed are under the `requiredSource` folder then you should change the `GetFolder` to something like

```
For Each file In fso.GetFolder(fso.BuildPath(ThisWorkbook.Path, "RequiredSource")).Files
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

The `vbs` file could be something like (assumes the previous `refreshXLS` is inside a module)

```
Option Explicit 

Const macroWorkbook = "TestData1.xlsm"
Const macroName = "refreshXLS"

Dim fso
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim workbook    
    With CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
        Set workbook = .Workbooks.Open(fso.BuildPath( _ 
            fso.GetFile( WScript.ScriptFullName ).ParentFolder.Path _ 
            , macroWorkbook _ 
        ))
        .Application.Run "'" & Replace(workbook.Name, "'", "''") & "'!" & macroName
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close
        .Quit
    End With 

    WScript.Quit
```

Comment: I have added that. But my vb script which is called from java also needs to be updated with relative path.
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\easyAutomation2017\GoEasy\requiredSource\TestData1.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Run "TestData1.xlsm!refreshXLS" 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit. Will the above change work for this too ? @MC ND

Comment: @Mehek, The `VBA` code iterates over the files stored in the same folder that the current `xlsm` file, independtly of how you start it. If the `vbscript` file is stored in the same folder it can be changed to retrieve its own path and open the `xlsm` in its same folder, BUT you have not included any information in the question about how/where the files are placed.

Comment: I have added my project structure. So myVBS script executes the Testdata1.xlsm!refreshExcel macro.
This is my script: I want to use relative path here. i tried using a lot of solution but it didn't help
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\easyAutomation2017\GoEasy\requiredSource\TestData1.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Run "TestData1.xlsm!refreshXLS" 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit @MC DN

Comment: DN Thank you so much, vbs script works :) 
But the "For Each file In fso.GetFolder(fso.BuildPath(ThisWorkbook.Path, "requiredSource")).Files" still fails , It says path not found.

Comment: @Mehek, because all (`xlsm` and `xlsx`/`xls`) your files are under `requiredSource`. Use the original line in the code sample (`fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path).Files`)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck with this for a long time :) @MC ND

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails to work because you changed the variable `Path`.

You put `Path = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullpath & "\TestData1.xlsm")` which means the **Path** is now a Workbook Object, not a String anymore.

I suggest you to start using `Option Explicit` as a habit. In VBE, Options --> tick *Require Variable Declaration*.

Comment: If this is VBA, `Path = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullpath & "\TestData1.xlsm")` won't make `Path` a `Workbook` object - objects have to be `Set` in VBA.  That line would have just given a "Object doesn't support this property or method" error because the `Workbook` object being returned by the `Workbooks.Open` method has no default property that can be cast to a non-object variable type.